# Why does my list view not appearing on the screen page

Tags: java, android, jdbc

Created a list view to obtain data from my database to show in the android screen. However it does not seem to be working. Can anyone point out what is wrong ?

Here is my classlistitem.java

```
public class classlistitems {

    public String eventname;

    public classlistitems(String eventname){
        this.eventname = eventname;

    }
    public String getJobname(){
        return eventname;
    }
}
```

And here is my fragment class

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobs,container,false);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        listview=view.findViewById(R.id.listviewjobsfragment);

        Conn = new ConnectionClass();
        itemarralylist = new ArrayList<classlistitems>();

        SyncData orderdata = new SyncData();
        orderdata.execute("");



        return view;


    }
    private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        Boolean Sucess = false;
        String z = ("");

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Syncing","Listview Loading",true);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String z) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (Sucess==false){
            }else{
                try{
                    myAppAdapter= new MyAppAdapter(itemarralylist,getActivity());
                    listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                    listview.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
                }catch (Exception ex){}
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                Connection con = Conn.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet Acess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Sucess = false;
                } else {
                    String query = "Select eventname,dateperiod from eventjobx;";
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    if (rs != null) {
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            try {

                                itemarralylist.add(new classlistitems(rs.getString("eventname")));
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Sucess = true;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Sucess = false;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Writer write = new StringWriter();
                ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(write));
                Sucess = false;

            }




            return z;
        }
    }
    public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        public class ViewHolder{
            TextView jobname;
        }
        public List<classlistitems> parkinglist;
        public Context context;
        ArrayList<classlistitems>arrayList;

        private MyAppAdapter(List<classlistitems>apps,Context context){
            this.parkinglist = apps;
            this.context = context;
            arrayList = new ArrayList<classlistitems>();
            arrayList.addAll(parkinglist);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return parkinglist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            if (rowView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater =getLayoutInflater();
                rowView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.listcontentfragment2, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.jobname = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvgeteventjobasd);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

            }else{
                viewHolder =(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.jobname.setText(parkinglist.get(position).getJobname()+"");
            return rowView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why is sql-server in the tags ?

Comment: Provide more detail about what issues are you experiencing.